# Adding dataset for geolocation

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, dataset, mapbox

I am trying to add the data coordinates by searching through addresses and save it to the dataset, but I am able to find the address on the search bar but it returns "save to dataset not available". I clearly shows the address below the search bar as recommended. Is there a way to save it to dataset?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add some pieces of code or more context pls ?

Comment: @JuanRambal Hi! actually I have resolved the issue! But Thank you for your reply!